# Getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { error when using downloaded ArcGIS API in PC without internet)

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, offline

I am trying to implement ArcGIS API offline. I have downloaded the zip file from [the site](https://developers.arcgis.com/downloads/#javascript) and followed the following changes, changed the baseUrl to my Apache IP copied the files to /var/www/html/ and replaced all occurances of https with http in dojo.js and init.js files (My server users http).

After that, I used the [HTML code](https://jsfiddle.net/praneeths/k4j2e3uq/2/) given in the installation isntructions to check if the installation is successful or not.

I tried opening/running the HTML in machines with internet, it worked perfectly, but when I try to run it in machines without internet connect , it shows "Uncaught syntaxError".

[image: Error Screenshot]

I feel like it has something to do with "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" in line number 68 in init.js ,but i dont know how to solve the error.

Edit 1 :- I have tried to understand the error and even remove the code which is causing the Extension. It appears that using catch like `catch{}` is causing this error. As far as I know, `catch(e){}` should have been the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of the browser. I encountered the same error. Only the supported versions of the browser mentioned in the [ArcGIS API for JavaScript System Requirements page](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/system-requirements/) can render the API correctly.

In my case, I used Google Chrome v62.x.x whereas the supported version of Chrome was v99.x.x or later.